# How to go from token value to lexer rule?

Tags: antlr4

So far I believed that a token value (as generated by a lexer rule) is the same as the rule index for that rule. Obviously that is not the case, as you can see when you look through the `ruleNames` and `literal/display names` fields in your generated code. Rule names are partially in a different order compared to display names (which are only the string representations for a token value) and also contain things like fragment rules. On the other hand there are no entries for virtual tokens (as defined in the `tokens` section).

Now when you want to get the rule index from a token value, how would you do that? The only way I can imagine is to get the symbolic name (which is the rule name) from the vocabulary and then look this up in the rule names array. But that seems a bit odd. There should be a more direct way. Any idea?

**Additional info:** the lookup is needed when you want to walk the ATN starting in a parser rule. Lexer tokens are stored as transition labels and that's where they come from. In order to continue walking in the lexer ATN you need the correct rule index.

Comment: Have you tried `Recognizer#getRuleIndexMap() ` accessed through the generated lexer? Looks like it should work, but have not tried.

Comment: Yep, that's the second step, once you have the rule name. However, I hoped there would be a direct way to get the rule number (and hence the start state).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this is not possible. Lexer rules can return tokens which don't correspond at all to the rule name. Hence there is no reliable relationship between tokens and the rules that produced them (often it matches, but not always).